# Как распарсить текстовый файл

Tags: php, парсер, text

Имеется файл

https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/8025044/1477559821.600304360.txt

его я получил из PDF. Теперь задача - распарсить его. Но для начала надо разделить на блоки.

[image: скриншот]

Пробовал через explode('\n', $file); но не получается, потому что похоже там нет абзаца. Как быть?

Comment: Всё, что относится к вопросу, должно быть в вопросе, а не ссылки на облачные хранилища

Comment: Наверное надо было `explode("\n", $file);` ибо в одинарных кавычках `\n` представляет саму себя а не перевод каретки

Comment: я бы делил не по "\n", а по "\n\n", т.к. там пустая строка есть.

Comment: Нужно два символа: **на** пустую строку и **с** неё. Плюс - не забываем о том, что может быть `\r\n`.

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
$content = file_get_contents("https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/8025044/1477559821.600304360.txt");
print_r(explode("\n\n", $content)); // Выведет массив, разбитый по параграфам
```